# Filtering array in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to show a certain picture. If a picture has `is_primary` property filled and true then I need to show that picture. Otherwise, I should just display whatever is first. Here is my code. It doesn't work, I see both `is_primary` picture and first. What am I doing wrong?

```
@php
  $check = 0
@endphp
@foreach ($ad->photos as $photo)
  @if ($photo->is_primary == true)
    <img src="{{$photo->filename}}" alt="{{$ad->name}}" class="card-image">
    @php
      $check = 1
    @endphp
  @endif
@endforeach

@if ($check > 0)
  <img src="{{$ad->photos->first()->filename}}" alt="{{$ad->name}}" class="card-image">
@endif
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the controller?  This sounds like business logic and not simple view logic.

Comment: I am passing the whole object to a view, but yeah maybe I can do something before sending data to a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue in you logic. If `is_primary` is true you are displaying image and set flag variable to **1**. And end of loop you are checking `$check > 0` so its true when `$check =1` you need to add condition `$check == 0`

```
@php
  $check = 0
@endphp
@foreach ($ad->photos as $photo)
  @if ($photo->is_primary == true)
    <img src="{{$photo->filename}}" alt="{{$ad->name}}" class="card-image">
    @php
      $check = 1
    @endphp
  @endif
@endforeach

@if ($check == 0)
  <img src="{{$ad->photos->first()->filename}}" alt="{{$ad->name}}" class="card-image">
@endif
```

OR you can check != 1

```
@if ($check != 1)
      <img src="{{$ad->photos->first()->filename}}" alt="{{$ad->name}}" class="card-image">
    @endif
```

Comment: I still get both pics. is_primary and the first one. I did this $check != 1 and it worked. I don't think I get how it works with !=

Comment: Read my answer I have explained you why you have to check `!= 1` hope you will get it